# typedef syntax clarification

Tags: c, struct

I have a bit of confusion between the below declarations - could you please help clear it up?

```c
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} example;
```

And this

```c
struct something {
  int a;
  int b;
} ob;
```

And I am not sure what the below would even mean?

```c
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
} bar;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} example;
```

This one defines an unnamed structure type and introduces `example` as a type alias for that structure type. You can therefore refer to that structure type only as `example.

```
struct something {
  int a;
  int b;
} ob;
```

This one defines a structure type `something` and also declares an object `ob` of that type. You can refer to the structure type only as `struct something`.

```
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
} bar;
```

This one defines a structure type named `foo` and introduces `bar` as a type alias for that structure type. You can refer to that structure type as `struct foo` or as `bar`.

Answer (score 4):

With

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} example;
```

you define an unnamed structure, but define a type-alias `example` for the structure. That means you can only create instance of the structures using the `example` "type", like e.g.

```
example my_example_structure;
```

With

```
struct something {
  int a;
  int b;
} ob;
```

you define a structure named `something`, and an instance (a variable) of that structure named `ob`. You can use `struct something` to create new variables of the structure:

```
struct something my_second_ob;
```

The variable `ob` can be used like any other instance of the structure:

```
printf("b = %d\n", ob.b);
```

Lastly, with

```
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
} bar;
```

you define a structure named `foo`, so you can use e.g. `struct foo` to define variables. You also define a type-alias `bar` which can also be used. Like for example

```
struct foo my_first_foo;
bar my_second_foo;
```

---

The general syntax for `typedef` is

```
typedef <actual type> <alias name>;
```

In the last case of your examples, the `<actual type>` is

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

and the `<alias name` is `bar`.